# Accept-Encoding is ignored when matching methods?

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I have a JAX-RS REST resource which should be able to respond in different charsets as indicated by the client's preference through the `Accept-Charset` header.

However, as JAX-RS seems to ignore the `Accept-Charset` header by default, I wrote two methods explicitly stating the two different charsets I want to support:

```
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces("text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
public String test_utf8() {
    return "Hello World";
}

@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces("text/plain; charset=cp1047")
public String test_cp1047() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

However, when now calling the method using curl:

```
curl -v -H "Accept-Charset: cp1047;q=1.0, *;q=0" "http://localhost:8080/rest/test" -H "Accept: text/plain"
```

The server responds in UTF-8:

```
> GET /rest/test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.3
> Accept-Charset: cp1047;q=1.0, *;q=0
> Accept: text/plain
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 19
< Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 21:29:11 GMT
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Hello World
```

In addition, a log message appears in the server log:

> 23:29:11,356 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default
> task-2) RESTEASY002142: Multiple resource methods match request "GET
> /test". Selecting one. Matching methods: [public java.lang.String
> org.example.RestResource.test_utf8(), public java.lang.String
> org.example.RestResource.test_cp1047()]

How can I force the server to honor the charset requested by the client?

Comment: You can use only one REST method instead of using two. In the body on the method you can set the response charset dynamically based on your business logic or the request: `return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(...).header("charset=UTF-8").build()`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a custom `ContainerResponseFilter` which parses the `Accept-Charset` header and uses the "best" charset as requested by the client:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR)
@HonorAcceptCharset
public class HonorAcceptCharsetFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    private static final Pattern AcceptedEncodingPattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z*0-9_\\-]+)(?:; *[qQ] *= *([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?))?");
    public static final String AcceptCharsetHeaderName = "Accept-Charset";
    public static final String ContentTypeHeaderName = "Content-Type";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        MediaType mediaType = responseContext.getMediaType();
        if (mediaType == null)
            return;

        Charset charset = this.determineCharset(requestContext);
        if (charset == null)
            return;

        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle(ContentTypeHeaderName, mediaType.withCharset(charset.name()));
    }

    private Charset determineCharset(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        String acceptCharset = requestContext.getHeaderString(AcceptCharsetHeaderName);
        if (acceptCharset == null)
            return null;

        List<Map.Entry<Charset, Double>> acceptedCharsets = Arrays.stream(acceptCharset.split(", *"))
                .map(this::parseAcceptedEncoding)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (acceptCharset.length() == 0)
            return null;
        if (acceptCharset.length() == 1)
            return acceptedCharsets.get(0).getKey();

        OptionalDouble maxQuality = acceptedCharsets.stream().mapToDouble(Map.Entry::getValue).max();
        List<Charset> candidates = acceptedCharsets.stream().filter(it -> it.getValue() == maxQuality.getAsDouble()).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (candidates.size() == 1)
            return candidates.get(0);

        if (candidates.stream().anyMatch(it -> it.name().toLowerCase().matches("utf-?8")))
            return StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        return candidates.get(0);
    }

    private Map.Entry<Charset, Double> parseAcceptedEncoding(String acceptedEncoding) {
        Matcher matcher = AcceptedEncodingPattern.matcher(acceptedEncoding);
        if (!matcher.find())
            return null;

        String charsetName = matcher.group(1);
        if ("*".equals(charsetName))
            return null;
        try {
            if (!Charset.isSupported(charsetName))
                return null;
        } catch (IllegalCharsetNameException ex) {
            return null;
        }

        Charset charset = Charset.forName(charsetName);

        String quality = matcher.group(2);
        double qualityNumber = StringUtils.isAllEmpty(quality) ? 1.0 : Double.parseDouble(quality);
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(charset, qualityNumber);
    }
}

@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface HonorAcceptCharset {
}
```

Now I just need one method which I can decorate with `@HonorAcceptCharset` in order to enable the filter (I don't want to enable it globally as I do not want to add charsets to binary types. Maybe the filter could look into the media type and determine if it wants to activate depending on a predefined list as an alternative.

Still strikes me somewhat strange that this kind of behaviour is not enabled by default.